# FTP Over SSL/TLS and Firewall Support

Tags: networking, ftp, network-protocols, firewall, ftps

Is there any open source/commercial FTP client which supports FTPS (FTP over SSL/TLS) over firewall/proxy? Since If we use SSL/TLS, the Control channel is encrypted and the Firewall couldn't understand the port used for data communication. But, If we use passive mode, is this limitation can be addressed?

Comment: belongs to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filezilla supports FTPS.

IF you configure Filezilla to use a very restricted set of ports, and open those in the firewall, then that should get around the issue with the control channel?

Comment: But, opening a set of ports lead to the security hole in the firewall itself.